# Subset columns in R dataframe issue?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe `df` that I want to subset in the following way:

Columns 1-7 and a vector of columns cols:

```
cols = c("rs1057079", "rs1057079.1", "rs4845882", "rs4845882.1", "rs1891932", "rs1891932.1", "rs530296", "rs530296.1", "rs10497340", "rs10497340.1")
```

So what I did is `df[, c(1:7, cols)]` but R throws an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , c(seq(1:7), SNPs_dup)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

What is wrong here?? I can subset on 1:7 and cols but why not on both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c(1:7, cols)` coerces the sequence `1:7` to characters which are further treated as columns names `'1', '2' ...` instead of column positions, you can extract the `1-7` column names and then concatenate with `cols` and subset:

```
df[,c(names(df)[1:7], cols)]
```

Or convert `cols` to positions:

```
df[,c(1:7, match(cols, names(df)))]
```

Comment: I see, but how to avoid c() to do this? This is the only way?

Comment: You can't stop `c` from doing this, since it produces an atomic vector which must have the same data type. I provided an alternative way for this.